# SFTP connection times out too soon

Tags: ssh, remote-access, sftp, scp

The SFTP connection to the server through a client(Cyberduck) times out too soon(1 min or so). Is there some default setting in the server that I can modify to change this situation?

EDIT: Figured it out. The problem is actually the newer version of Cyberduck. It's getting disconnected no matter what server I SFTP to. Going to accept the answer anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ClientAliveInterval` in `sshd_config` on your server controls this.  Default is 60 seconds.

Comment: +1 - but you should also mention ClientAliveCountMax and/or TCPKeepAlive